# RouterLink page displays nothing

Tags: angular, typescript, service, single-page-application, angular-routerlink

Please assist, I just started learning angular and I'm having issues with my routerLink page.When I click on the routerLink it takes me to the page but displays blankpage but when I open the developer tools the page displays. what could be the issue.

My menu template

```
<div class="container" 
    fxLayout="column"
    fxLayoutGap="10px">
    
    <div fxFlex>
        <div>
            <h3>Menu</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div fxFlex>
        <mat-grid-list cols="2" *ngIf="dishes" rowHeight="200px">
            <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let dish of dishes" [routerLink]= "['/dishdetail', dish.id]">
                <img height="200px" src={{dish.image}} alt={{dish.image}}>
                <mat-grid-tile-footer>
                    <h1> {{dish.name | uppercase}} </h1>
                </mat-grid-tile-footer>
            </mat-grid-tile>
        </mat-grid-list>
    </div>
```

Menu component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Dish } from '../shared/dish';

import { DishService } from '../services/dish.service';


@Component({

  selector: 'app-menu',

  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',

  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.scss']
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

  dishes: Dish[];

   
  constructor(private dishService: DishService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dishes = this.dishService.getDishes();
  }
}
```

Dishdetail component.ts where the id is to be fetched.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { Params, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Dish } from '../shared/dish';
import { DishService } from '../services/dish.service';
import { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes';


@Component({

  selector: 'app-dishdetail',

  templateUrl: './dishdetail.component.html',

  styleUrls: ['./dishdetail.component.scss']
})
export class DishdetailComponent implements OnInit {

    dish: Dish;
  

    constructor(private dishService:DishService,
                private route: ActivatedRoute,
                private location: Location) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      const id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
        this.dish = this.dishService.getDish(id);

      
    }

    previousPage(): void {
      this.location.back();
    }
}
```

Dishdetail template that is meant to display when clicked on routerLink on menu template.

```
<div class="container"
    fxLayout="row"
    fxLayout.sm="column"
    fxLayout.xs="column"
    fxLayoutAlign.gt-md="space-around center"
    fxLayoutGap="10px">



    <div fxFlex>
        <mat-grid-list colums="2" rowHeight="">
            <div *ngIf="dish" fxFlex="40">
                    <mat-card>
                        <mat-card-header>
                            <mat-card-title>
                                <h3>{{dish.name | uppercase}}</h3>
                            </mat-card-title>
                        </mat-card-header>
                        <img mat-card-image src= {{dish.image}} alt="dish">
                        <mat-card-content>
                            <p> {{ dish.description }} </p>
                        </mat-card-content>
                        <mat-card-actions>
                            <button mat-button (click)="previousPage()" >BACK</button>
                            <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
                            <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
                        </mat-card-actions>
                    </mat-card>
                
            </div>


            <div fxFlex="40">   
                    <mat-list *ngIf ="dish">
                        <h2>Comments</h2>
                        <mat-list-item *ngFor="let comment of dish.comments">
                            <p matLine><span> {{ comment.comment }} </span></p>
                            <p matLine><span> {{ comment.rating }} Stars</span></p>
                            <p matLine><span> -- {{ comment.author }} {{ comment.date | date }} </span></p>
                        </mat-list-item>
                    </mat-list>
            </div>
    
        </mat-grid-list>

</div>
```

My service file.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Dish } from '../shared/dish';

import { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes';


@Injectable({

  providedIn: 'root'

})

export class DishService {

  constructor() { }

  getDishes():Dish[]{
    return DISHES;
  }

  getDish(id:string):Dish{

    return DISHES.filter(dish =>  dish.id === id)[0];
  }

  getFeaturedDish():Dish{
    return DISHES.filter(dish => dish.featured)[0];
  }
}
```

I want to display each dishes on a new page when click on in the menu template.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your code I can't find any mention to the

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This tag is in charge of displaying the component requested by the `routerLink`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot I've figured it out.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).